# Displaying search results if more than one template group

Tags: templates, search, url, navee

i have been pulling my hair out trying to understand this so any help is appreciated.

I have a channel 'Content' which is just the 'pages' of the site. My template groups are setup using only the 'index' template: template_group/template

eg,

coaching/index
management/index

And my navigation (done using Navee): template_group/entry1 (from 'Content' channel)

coaching/schools
coaching/instructors
management/forms

All straight forward. Now i have a simple search form which i want people to be able to search the entries on the site (from the 'Content' channel) but i need to know how to produce the correct search results page.

In channel preferences > path settings > channel URL ...
..my 'Content' channel does not have a specific url - since it is different depending on the template group.

eg, If i enter and save http://www.example.com/coaching/ into the field, then do a search for 'schools', the results display http://www.example.com/coaching/schools    which is correct. But if i search 'forms' the results brings up http://www.example.com/coaching/forms instead of http://www.example.com/management/forms

So since the 'Content' channel does not have a specific 'Channel URL', how do i get search results to product the link to the correct page/entry??

UPDATE. My Solution.
I created categories for each of the six template groups, then assigned each page/entry to a category. I then used the below conditionals to produce the correct search results:

```
{if category_url_title == "ONE"}
<h3><a href="/ONE/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>{/if}

{if category_url_title == "TWO"}
<h3><a href="/TWO/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>{/if}

{if category_url_title == "THREE"}
<h3><a href="/THREE/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>{/if}
```

etc, etc..

Ps. Using the above with {excerpt} just duplicated the excerpt from the first result, to each other result. So instead of excerpt i used a custom field (meta description text field).

Answer (score 1):

ZEDG: if I'm understanding your setup correctly, each entry in your 'Content' channel equates to a specific page on the site, right? So each 'page' has its own entry_id. Thus, you could run a conditional to examine on the entry_id of each result, and provide specific template code for each possibility. (Switchee would be a better option for this task than native if/else conditionals, as it would only parse the template code for the matching entry_id, rather than parsing the code for every possible entry_id and then discarding the non-matches).

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately there are too many entries overall to make that feasible (if i understand your meaning). .. I have instead run a conditional based on what category each 'page'/entry belongs to (being one of the template groups).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to assign each channel a category and then base the url slugs on that in the search result output.

Comment: Do you mean assign a category to each template group? There is only the one main channel 'Content'.